# Rapier.js joint is wobbly

Tags: javascript

So I was working with the rapier.js physics engine but I have been struggling with making kinges work. I wanted to make a simple floating block, this are the coords and scale of the two blocks:

Block 1

```
{ x: 0, y: 13, z: 0 }, { x: 5, y: 5, z: 5 }
```

Block 2

```
{x: 5, y: 8, z: 5 }, { x: 5, y: 5, z: 5 }
```

This is the joint I am making

```
let params = rapier.JointData.spherical({ x: 2.5, y: -2.5, z: -2.5 }, { x: -2.5, y: 2.5, z: 2.5 });
let joint = world.createImpulseJoint(params, body1.userData.physicsBody, body2.userData.physicsBody, true);
```

What happens is that the joint is wobbly and the hinges, which should coincide with the corners of the two blocks, do not stay connected, like there is space in between.

[image]

If anybody knows how to fix this, thank you

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope nothing unfortunately